# Check if user is anonymous for Flask-Cache `unless` argument

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-cache

I am trying to cache a view unless the user is logged in.  `current_user` only works inside a view though, so I'm having trouble passing it to `unless=`.  How do I do this correctly?

```
@app.route("/")
@app.cache.cached(timeout=300, unless=current_user.is_authenticated())
def index():
    return 'stuff to return'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the call in a `lambda`.  Flask-Cache will call the function when the view is executed, rather than once when the view is defined.

```
@app.cache.cached(timeout=300, unless=lambda: current_user.is_authenticated)
```

The [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.cached) specifically say that `unless` should be a callable that will be executed each time.